# UIActivityViewController - No share options - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented a UIActivityViewController in Swift 5 via a nav bar button and upon click this should share the contents of an array called sharedData.

When clicking the button, the share options popup is empty.

Here is my func code:

```
    @IBAction func shareNavButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let shareItems: [Any] = [sharedData]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is my entire VC code:

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func shareNavButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let shareItems: [Any] = [sharedData]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        convertArray()
    }
}

extension FavoritesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return sharedData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = sharedData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
                sharedData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                saveArray()
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                completionHandler(true)
            }
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
            } else {
                // Fallback to default action
            }
            deleteAction.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
            return configuration
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let copyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Copy") { (_, _, completionHandler) in

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            UIPasteboard.general.string = cell?.textLabel?.text

            completionHandler(true)
        }
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            copyAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard")
        } else {
            // fall back to default action
        }
        copyAction.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [copyAction])
        return configuration
    }

}
```

Comment: what type of `sharedData`

Comment: Sorry, didn’t specify, String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an array of string inside another array. Your sharedData is an array.

```
let shareItems: [Any] = [sharedData]
```

Try with this code:

```
let shareItems: [Any] = sharedData
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!